# Irish cream left in hot car

Tags: food-safety

I recently left a new unopened bottle of Irish cream in my vehicle for 24 hours. It probably reached temps of over 100F. How do I know if it's bad?

Comment: In shipping 100F is not uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. There's enough alcohol to prevent anything from growing in it. The worst that will happen is that it could get clumpy, which would be unpleasant and obvious.